# Understanding challenge "a^b is considered powerful iff a^b >= 2 * b^2 and a^b >= (a*b)^2"

Tags: ruby

Can you help I don't understand challenge from https://www.learneroo.com/modules/61/nodes/338#stq=&stp=0

Challenge
ab is considered powerful if (and only if) both of the following 2 conditions are met:
    ab >= 2 * b2
    ab >= (a*b)2
return true if ab is powerful and false otherwise.

my answer

```
def do_stuff(a, b)
  a*b >= 2*b*2
  a*b >= (a*b)*2

end


#boilerplate code
t = gets.to_i
for i in 1..t do
    a, b = gets.strip.split.map {|i| i.to_i}
    puts do_stuff(a, b)
end

Input   Correct Output  Your Output
2 4        false         false
3 5        true          false
10 1       false         false
7 15       true          false
6 2        false         false
4 5        true          false
4 3        false         false
```

Comment: The challange asks about 'a to the b-th power', not 'product of a and b'. Use exponentiation in your formula.

Comment: def do_stuff(a, b)
  a**b >= 2*b**2
  a**b >= (a*b)**2
10x BRO
end

Comment: rather a**b >= 2*b*b AND a**b >= (a*b)**2. Generally, a**b is pow(a,b) but only if b is integer exponent.